# Multiple threads to call the same function. Remove all threads once a condition turns true

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm currently creating multiple `Threads` to call a function which checks if a statement turns true inside a `while loop`.

**My problem:**

I'm creating for example 10 different threads which run the same function at the same time, which works fine so far. But once the bool `isAviable` turns true the other code inside the else check will be executed 10 times since there are 10 threads running.

Could I somehow stop the other threads and just continue with 1 Thread once the bool isAviable turns true?

**Example how the threads are started:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(function)) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
}
```

**Example of the function which gets called:**

```
private void function()
{
    try
    {
        bool isAviable = false;

        while (isAviable == false)
        {
            isAviable = checkFunction(bunifuMetroTextbox3.Text);

            if (isAviable == false)
            {
                base.Invoke(new Action(method_5));
            }
            else
            {
                // Ececute other function code which should only be executed by one thread..
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**Example checkFunction:**

```
private bool checkFunction(string handle)
{
    bool aviable = false;

    while (!aviable)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                if (client.DownloadString("http://url.com/script.php?user=" + handle).Contains("No users found"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch(WebException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Since you're doing IO work and not CPU bound work you shouldn't be creating multiple threads in the first place, just do the web requests asynchronously.

Comment: So i should create one thread to call the function and just run the checkFunction which contains the webrequest asynchronously using parallel.for for example?

Comment: You don't need to create any threads at all here, not even a single additional thread.  `Parallel.For` doesn't help you do asynchronous work at all, it's another just a way of doing CPU bound work using multiple threads, and it requires that the work be done synchronously, and is itself synchronous, not asynchornous.

Comment: Lacking a good [mcve], your question is too broad. The code you posted doesn't make much sense anyway. Ten different threads _all_ trying to access the same URL? What's the point of that? And what's the point of the `aviable` variable in the `checkFunction()` method? You never set it to anything other than `false` and the loop will execute until `DownloadString()` completes without an exception. And no delays between requests? I pity the poor server you're spamming with web requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So since the work that you're doing is IO bound, not CPU bound, you shouldn't be creating new threads.  You should simply be using asynchronous methods for your IO, in order to keep your UI responsive, rather than creating threads that are just going to spend all of their time sitting around doing nothing.  This is a simple enough change to your method that checks if a given user is available:

```
private async Task<bool> IsUserAvaliable(string handle)
{
    while (true)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                string content = await client.GetStringAsync("http://url.com/script.php?user=" + handle);
                return content.Contains("No users found");
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next, for the calling method, it simplifies the code radically to have it simply represent determining when the user becomes available, and not considering what needs to be done when it is:

```
private async Task CheckUntilUserIsAvaliable()
{
    //presumably bunifuMetroTextbox3 shouldn't be hard coded, but instead passed in, but it's unclear
    while (!await IsUserAvaliable(bunifuMetroTextbox3.Text))  
    {
        method_5();
        await Task.Delay(1000); //adjust as appropriate for what the poll time should be
    }
}
```

Next we can create a method to call `CheckUntilUserIsAvaliable` 10 different times, and we can use `WhenAny` to determine when any one of them finishes.  After one of them has finished, we can do whatever work needs to be done when the first user has become available:

```
private async Task CheckUntilOneOfTheUsersIsAvaliable()
{
    await Task.WhenAny(Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
        .Select(i => CheckUntilUserIsAvaliable()));
    //Work to be done when any one of the checking operations has indicated that it's avalaible
}
```